# Popover not displaying correctly

Tags: ios, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, popover, uisplitview

I'm following a demo about hiding the left side of a Split View when the iPad is in Portrait, and then showing it as a Popover when a button placed in a toolbar is pressed. I followed everything step-by-step and it works (sort of) except that when I press the button, instead of in a Popover the view is displayed sliding from left to right. I also noticed that I can get the same result by sliding my finger from left to right instead of pressing the button.
This is the code I use (same code works properly in the demo).

in the View Controller of the view that should be shown in the Popover:

```
-(BOOL)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController*)svc
  shouldHideViewController:(UIViewController*)vc
             inOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation
{
    return [self splitViewBarButtonItemPresenter] ? UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation) : NO;
}

-(void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc
    willHideViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController
         withBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem
      forPopoverController:(UIPopoverController *)pc
{
    barButtonItem.title = self.title;
    [self splitViewBarButtonItemPresenter].splitViewBarButtonItem = barButtonItem;
}

-(void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc
    willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController
 invalidatingBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem
{
    [self splitViewBarButtonItemPresenter].splitViewBarButtonItem = nil;
}
```

And in the View that should display the Popover:

```
-(void)setSplitViewBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)splitViewBarButtonItem
{
    if (_splitViewBarButtonItem != splitViewBarButtonItem){
        NSMutableArray *toolbarItems = [self.toolbar.items mutableCopy];
        if (_splitViewBarButtonItem) [toolbarItems removeObject:_splitViewBarButtonItem];
        if (splitViewBarButtonItem) [toolbarItems insertObject:splitViewBarButtonItem atIndex:0];
        self.toolbar.items = toolbarItems;
        _splitViewBarButtonItem = splitViewBarButtonItem;
    }
}
```

`SplitViewBarButtonItemPresenter` is just a protocol used to delegate who should show (you guessed it!) the button for the popover.

Comment: ever fix this? im having the same issue

Comment: I'm stuck with this same problem too. Any help?